# Am i thinking clearly here in creating a new object?

Tags: javascript, methods, properties, javascript-objects, global

```
let person = {

name:"kevin",
eyeColor:"blue",
age: 34,
address: {

street: "12 havering road",
town: "romford", 

house: {
type: "terraced",
bedrooms: 3,

}
},
updateAge: function () { 

let age = ++person.age;
return age;

}
};

console.log(person.updateAge());
let details = person.address.house;
alert(details.type);
```

Hello everyone, I have a burning question in regards to objects. I must say when i am watching tutorials on this , most are unclear as i like to understand concepts instead of just end goal's but i cant seem to find much material in regards to the concepts so after several hours of playing with the console. i have come up with this. I may be completely wrong but need to ask for my sanity. The code above i am imagining var person as the global window object. Address as the document( a property of the window object) . house as the getElementById ( i know thats a method compared to a property but im only focusing on the pathway accessing properties and methods in objects. Then im assuming im assigning all to a varialbe and then .type is like .innerHTML.
So although obviously funcitonally not the same. am i correct in saying including the window global object the pathway to e.g.

```
var box = window.document.getElementById('box');
box.innerHTML =
```

IS THE SAME AS

```
var box = person.address.house;
box.type =
```

Obvs ignore the functionality but the pathway of creating my own objects, am i correct in saying is a similar setup ?

thanks all

Comment: Yes, you are correct in thinking that there's a similarity between the two in terms of how it looks/the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking. window.document.getElementById('box').innerHTML is similar to calling person.address.house.type. However, I must point out that the window object is a built in javascript object and your person object was created by you. The window object is made up of a bunch of properties and methods, which then contains nested properties and methods, which is similar to your person object!

If you ever want to see what properties and methods an object contains you can use console.dir():

```
console.dir(window);

let person = {

name:"kevin",
eyeColor:"blue",
age: 34,
address: {

street: "12 havering road",
town: "romford", 

house: {
type: "terraced",
bedrooms: 3,

}
},
updateAge: function () { 

let age = ++person.age;
return age;

}
};
console.dir(person);
```

Comment: fantastic, thanks for the reply. im relieved im not miles off and have gone down a blind alley all day, would you agree there's not much material which describes ths concept but mainly focuses on the end goal of creating objects and the end goal ?

Comment: @KevinGreetham I would agree there isn't much explaining this concept if you are learning this by yourself. But keep in mind that a good rule of thumb for JavaScript is that everything is an object. If we create an array in code like var x = []; suddenly we get access to a bunch of methods and properties we didn't write. Such as array length like x.length. This is because when creating an array we create a new instance of the array object, which is like a blueprint JS contains that says every array gets these methods and properties. So long answer short, everything in JS is an object.

Comment: thank so much, just one more quesiton if you could be so kind. I am learning this by myself , i started 2 months ago after learning HTML and CSS floats and flexbox layouts. The question i have is when you say everything is an object , can you give me a few examples ? e.g. Do properties inside of objects then become objects themselves? thanks

Comment: @KevinGreetham want to hop on a zoom call and I can show you? I don't know if I can type it all

Comment: omg that would be amazing, id be so appreciative, shall i set one up or you ?

Comment: You can set it up just send a link!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219369/discussion-between-klaurtar1-and-kevin-greetham).

Comment: https://us04web.zoom.us/j/77643086658?pwd=MGl4VmR1Y21SaE01TmpjRFljT0RFUT09